# How to transform XYZ Directory tiles to other tile format?

Tags: postgis, tiles, mbtiles

I am quite newbie to hosting / providing tiles. I have created my own tiles in XYZ directory format and my plan was to serve them through an URL like mywebsite.com/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg

However, I reached the file limit on my server and I am wondering how I could serve the tiles in a different way. As I understand tiles in mbtiles format basically consist of just a single sqlite file (which would solve my file limit problem I guess).

Or could I store them in a PostGIS database?

I am still kind of lost right now and would need some guidance on a strategy of how to serve my already existent tiles to a client.